# How to multiple query results in order to reduce the query number?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to list comments from my database depending on their type.

There are three types of comments in my database and I call them with three different queries.

```
//01 - Awaiting Comments
  $query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed = 0");

  $query->execute();
  $r = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<h1>Awaiting Comments</h1>";
    foreach($r as $r_)  {
    echo "<li>r_[title]</li>";
  }
//02 - Comments waiting for confirmation
  $query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed = 2");

  $query->execute();
  $r = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<h1>Comments waiting for confirmation</h1>";
    foreach($r as $r_)  {
    echo "<li>r_[title]</li>";
  }

//03 - Confirmed comments
  $query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed = 1");

  $query->execute();
  $r = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<h1>Confirmed Comments</h1>";
    foreach($r as $r_)  {
    echo "<li>r_[title]</li>";
  }
```

With my current code i get the output i want like that:

```
Awaiting Comments
-comment 1
-comment 8
-comment 5

Comments waiting confirmation
-comment 9
-comment 4
-comment 2

Confirmed Comments
-comment 3
-comment 6
-comment 7
```

Is there any way to get same output with single query instead of three of them?

Comment: what about `SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE confirmed in (0,1,2) GROUP BY confirmed` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PDO is a bit more than everyone thinks it is. For example, it has a magnificent feature for you, called [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group).

Not to mention other little improvements that can make your code dramatically shorter.

```
$r = $handler->query("SELECT confirmed, c.* FROM comments c")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

*Is all the code you need.*

here you are selecting the `confirmed` field first and then tell PDO to group (or "multiply") the results based on its value.

And now you can print your comments wherever you want

```
// Awaiting Comments
foreach($r[0] as $r_) {
    echo "<li>$r_[title]</li>";
}

// Confirmed comments
foreach($r[2] as $r_) {
    echo "<li>$r_[title]</li>";
}
```

Or, to make it in one loop

```
$titles = [
    0 => 'Awaiting Comments',
    2 => 'Comments waiting confirmation',
    1 => 'Confirmed Comments',
];

foreach ($titles as $code => $title)
{
    echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
    foreach($r[$code] as $r_) {
        echo "<li>$r_[title]</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: For others that find this solution and can't get it to work...  Given column 'confirmed' you wish to group by, which is contained in table 'comments', then the following is what worked for me: $r = $handler->query("SELECT confirmed, comments.* FROM comments")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

I don't know what the 'c' is that is in the above answer.  

On the other hand, thank you so much!  This is code shortening solution I have been looking for.

Comment: @Trialsman "c" is the same as your "comments". Read up on the table name aliases in SQL

Comment: @Your_Common_Sense Yes, I have now read up on SQL table aliases. I couldn't figure out the significance of the 'c' because it seemed so random. I saw the same thing in the examples on phpdelusions, which I assume is your site.  I must have incorrectly typed when I tried to use the alias version.  While in this simple example the alias saves five or six keystrokes, I can see how this would be very useful in a more complex example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
WHERE (confirmed >= 0 AND confirmed < 3 ) 
ORDER BY FIELD(confirmed,0,2,1)
```

In this way you have all rows sorted by your desired output.

If the `confirmed` field allows only 0,1,2 values, you can sempliy in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
ORDER BY FIELD(confirmed,0,2,1)
```

Then:

```
while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
{
    if    ( $row['confirmed'] == 0 )
    {
        (...)
    }
    elseif( $row['confirmed'] == 1 )
    {
        (...)
    }
    else
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use and `IN` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed IN (0, 1, 2)
```

Then you can loop through the results as many times as you like to create the output.

Comment: You can also use `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed = 0 OR confirmed = 1 OR confirmed = 2`, the only downside is is that it is longer.

Comment: with `ORDER BY` you are also able to make fewer loops afterwards, because then you only need to loop once

Comment: That's right @Tom, using `IN` is basically using `OR`'s

Comment: My intention to post that was so you could put in in your answer so that the OP has 2 options to choose from instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks @Tom but I see no need to provide an alternative when the more compact code is well documented and will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE confirmed=1 OR confirmed=2 OR confirmed=0`
Or use `IN`